# How to configure AWS glue crawler to read csv file having comma in dataset?

Tags: aws-glue-data-catalog

I have data as follow in csv file in S3 bucket:

```
"Name"|"Address"|"Age" 
----------------------
"John"|"LA,USA"|"27"
```

I have created the crawler which has created the table and when I am trying to query data on Athena. Getting following data:

[image]

How to configure the AWS glue Crawler to create catalog table to read above data?

Answer (score 2):

You must have figured it out already, but thought this answer would benefit anyone visits this question.

This can be resolved either using Crawler classifier or making modifications to table properties after table is created.

Using classifier:

1. Create classifier with "Quote symbol"
   [image]
2. Add Classifer in Crawler you create.
   [image]

Or you can modify table SerDe properties by editing table (after crawler creates table):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once the crawler run is done and table created, go to the glue table,edit the table definition and change the SerDe library to OpenCSVSerDe.

[image]

Then query the table using Athena.

[image]

Comment: full value for OpenCSVSede: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde